# How to wait in Objective-C, maybe better in blocks?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks

I know of:

`performSelector:afterDelay:` and these, but I always have to make an extra method for every delay.
In `Cocos2d-iphone` I use a `CCAction` for that `CCTimeDelay`, within a `CCSequence`. Would be cool if it would also work outside of `Cocos2d`.

## 1.

If I want to wait, lets say 1.3 seconds and don't want to split the method in half because of that, what should I do?

## 2.

I know when I want to wait and don't change the context, the thread will do nothing. So the performSelector methods are good for that.

How to make it happen, that not the whole app waits, userInput should be accepted while waiting.
Let's say I want to create an animation of two steps, in between there should be an time interval of 0.8 seconds. To keep it in one method but use **multithreading** I use **blocks** then (any other idea appreciated).
How to wait inside the block, so the main thread won't get disturbed?

Comment: Type `dispatch_after` in the Xcode editor, and watch the code completion magic :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) way of performing blocks? It will allow you to have the code at the same place, without extra methods.

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //  Do whatever you want
});
```

You can replace `dispatch_get_main_queue()` with your own queue. Read more at [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

You don't need to remember all this stuff. Just start writing `dispatch_after` inside method and Xcode's code sense will offer you code snippet to auto generate (as MartinR pointed in comment on the question)

Comment: You are welcome. However I really don't know who downvoted my answer. Maybe just to stand out with his late answer .. ? :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC*delay),
  dispatch_get_current_queue(), block);
```